# Разделение строки из символов char[] на лексеми

Tags: c++, строки, char, strtok

Каким образом я бы мог осуществить решение к следующей задаче:
Необходимо виделить из заданой строки все возможные числа представленные в 16ричной СИ и которые в обязательном порядке начинаются с '0x'. Но пользуясь функцией strtok, нету возможности использовать разделители '0' и 'x' как одно целое. Важно использование именно символьного массива.

```
char str[] = "Is 0x40 is equal to 56? Is 0 x56 be a hex?"
char *path = strtok(str, "0x")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//сначала находим
char* p = strstr(str, "0x"), 
    //затем берем лексему
     *path = strtok(p, " "); 
cout << path ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот мой взгляд на решение этой задачи ***(Необходимо виделить из заданой строки все возможные числа представленные в 16ричной СИ и которые в обязательном порядке начинаются с '0x'. )***

Не хотите пользоваться strtok - не пользуйтесь)

Предложение такое - разбиваем строку на лексемы, и проверяем является ли лексема форматом hex (0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+), если да то (для примера) загоняем в контейнер (ну или что Вам надо там) )))

2 Вариант - регулярка  (0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+) опять бьем на лексамы и все в регулярку) Далее делайте что Вам в первом варианте)) ну или что Вам там надо)

по сути 1ый и 2ой вариант мало чем отличаются)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>


std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> GetHexValueFromString(const std::string& line) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> res;

    std::istringstream ist(line);
    std::stringstream hex_convect;
    std::string tmp_str;
    int value;

    while (ist >> tmp_str) {
        if (tmp_str.size() > 2 && 
            tmp_str.compare(0, 2, "0x") == 0 &&
            tmp_str.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF", 2) == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << tmp_str << " finded!" << std::endl;
            hex_convect << std::hex << tmp_str;
            hex_convect >> value;
            hex_convect.clear();
            res.push_back({tmp_str, value});
        }
    }

    return res;
}


void GetHexValueFromString2(const std::string& line) {
    // форматом hex (0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)
    std::regex rgx{"0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+"};

    std::istringstream ist(line);
    std::string tmp_str;

    while (ist >> tmp_str) {
         if (std::regex_match(tmp_str, rgx)) {
             // тупо вывод - без логики (пример)
             std::cout << tmp_str <<  " finded" << std::endl;
         }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::string line{"Is 0x40 is equal to 56? Is 0 x56 be a hex?"};

    auto vec{GetHexValueFromString(line)};

    if (!vec.size()) {
        std::cout << "No hex in line!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (const auto val : vec) {
            std::cout << "str : "<< val.first << " ; val = " << val.second << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "second test : " << std::endl;
    GetHexValueFromString2(line);

    return 0;
}
```